# Named pipes error 40 from Console app

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2005, console-application

I am having some difficulty connecting to a sql 2005 instance, from my development machine. The database server is out on the open interwebs. The database server runs on a non-standard port, so I have an alias configured in sql config manager.

I have been using this database for ages for development of a web app. I can connect to it no problem from the web app running via visual studio + cassini from my dev machine. Also, I can connect to it (via the alias) just fine with sql server management studio.

Yet when I run my console app, I get a named pipes error 40 error when I try to open the connection. I am using an IDENTICAL connection string, and identical code.

I'm tearing my hair out - there is so much out there when you google about how to deal with this error, but its usually a case of it works or it doesn't - not it works in management studio, and a web app, but not a console app.

Has anyone had anything similar, or have any pointers that may help?

thanks

slip

Answer (score 0):

Probably the [Client Protocols Configuration](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181035%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) for your account has named pipes protocol enabled and higher priority than TCP (which is the default situation), while the web service account has it disabled or lower priority than TCP (which is something that was once done explicitly to change it from the default). You could either disable named pipes from your own account client protocol settings (the link above shows how) or, preferably, you could explicitly force TCP from the connection string, see [How to use the server name parameter in a connection string to specify the client network library](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313295).